# How to install shoes on cygwin?

Tags: cygwin, apt-get

This is a common problem, not only with shoes. Almost every installation for linux involves apt-get install or yum install. Using cygwin it's impossible to use those commands. What's the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't find the solution, switched to linux.